# Rabbitmqctl command throws error

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I am trying to create a 3 node cluster on RabbitMQ. I have the first node up and running. When I issue join cluster command from node 2, it is throwing an error that node is down.

```
rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@hostname02
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Status of node rabbit@hostname02 ...
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@hostname02: nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@hostname02]

rabbit@hostname02:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on hostname02
  * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
                  no other nodes on hostname02
  * suggestion: start the node

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-30@hostname02'
- home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- cookie hash: bygafwoj/ISgb3yKej1pEg==
```

This is my config file.

```
[
  {rabbit, [
    {cluster_nodes, {[rabbit@hostname01, rabbitmq@hostname02, rabbit@hostname03], disc}},
    {cluster_partition_handling, ignore},
    {tcp_listen_options,
         [binary,
         {packet,        raw},
         {reuseaddr,     true},
         {backlog,       128},
         {nodelay,       true},
         {exit_on_close, false}]
    },
    {default_user, <<"guest">>},
    {default_pass, <<"guest">>},
    {log_levels, [{autocluster, debug}, {connection, info}]}
  ]},
  {kernel, [

  ]},
  {rabbitmq_management, [
    {listener, [
      {port, 15672}
    ]}
  ]}
].
% EOF
```

I have updated the `/etc/hosts` file with the details of all 3 nodes on all the 3 servers. I am not sure where I am getting this wrong.

Comment: Also I am getting this error in the logs.

`error,{inconsistent_cluster,"Node rabbit@hostname02 thinks it's clustered with node rabbit@hostname01, but rabbit@hostname01 disagrees"}}`

Comment: Have you figured this out? what does `rabbitmqctl status` on the affected node tell you?

Comment: Yes, seems like I have used the shortname instead of the fqdn. I have made the necessary changes in the hosts file. It worked.